# AngularJS localization via Prerender.io

Tags: angularjs, facebook-opengraph, prerender

I developed a website using AngularJS and I'm using [Prerender.io](http://prerender.io) (SaaS plan) to render my pages as pure HTML when scrapped from a bot (such as Facebook, Google, etc.).

My website is multi-language and does use [angular-translate](https://github.com/angular-translate/angular-translate), which allows **localization based on web browser language**. However, when scrapped from Facebook (for example), there's no browser and default language is always used *(Prerender.io acts as a server)*. Is it possible to tell Facebook scrapping tools to send the default user language, so that the website preview is generated in the user language?

Answer (score 0):

It all relies on Facebook-specific `og` tags. Include `og:locale` tag with your default language and `og:locale:alternate` for each additional language you support. Facebook crawler will then add both a special token and a special URL parameter when requesting your webpage.

```html
<meta property="og:locale" content="en_US" />
<meta property="og:locale:alternate" content="fr_FR" />
<meta property="og:locale:alternate" content="es_ES" />
```

You can find detailed instructions on official Facebook documentation [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/guides/internationalization).